# A better way to handle async tests in jasmine 2

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine, jasmine2.0

This is an example of three of my tests...

```
  describe('Enabled button (no disabled attribute)', function () {
    var el, clicked = false;

    beforeEach(function (done) {
      // Create the tag
      el = document.createElement('rui-button')
      el.innerHTML = 'Test Button';
      document.body.appendChild(el)

      el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        clicked = true;
        done();
      });

      // Mount the tag
      tag = riot.mount('rui-button')[0]
      expect(tag).toBeDefined();
      expect(tag.isMounted).toBe(true);
      tag.update();

      el.childNodes[0].click();
    });

    it('should be disabled', function () {
      expect(el.getAttribute('data-disabled')).toEqual('false');
      expect(clicked).toEqual(true);

      var style = window.getComputedStyle(el.childNodes[0]);
      expect(style.cursor).toEqual('pointer');
      expect(style.opacity).toEqual('1')
    });
  });

  describe('Enabled button (disabled="{ false }")', function () {
    var el, clicked = false;

    beforeEach(function (done) {
      // Create the tag
      el = document.createElement('rui-button')
      el.innerHTML = 'Test Button';
      el.setAttribute('disabled', '{ false }');
      document.body.appendChild(el)

      el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        clicked = true;
        done();
      });

      // Mount the tag
      tag = riot.mount('rui-button')[0]
      expect(tag).toBeDefined();
      expect(tag.isMounted).toBe(true);
      tag.update();

      el.childNodes[0].click();
    });

    it('should be disabled', function () {
      expect(el.getAttribute('data-disabled')).toEqual('false');
      expect(clicked).toEqual(true);

      var style = window.getComputedStyle(el.childNodes[0]);
      expect(style.cursor).toEqual('pointer');
      expect(style.opacity).toEqual('1')
    });
  });

  describe('Disabled button (disabled)', function () {
    var el, clicked = false;

    beforeEach(function (done) {
      // Create the tag
      el = document.createElement('rui-button')
      el.innerHTML = 'Test Button';
      el.setAttribute('disabled', '');
      document.body.appendChild(el)

      el.addEventListener('click', function () {
        clicked = true;
        done();
      });

      // Mount the tag
      tag = riot.mount('rui-button')[0]
      expect(tag).toBeDefined();
      expect(tag.isMounted).toBe(true);
      tag.update();

      el.childNodes[0].click();
    });

    it('should be disabled', function () {
      expect(el.getAttribute('data-disabled')).toEqual('true');
      expect(clicked).toEqual(false);

      var style = window.getComputedStyle(el.childNodes[0]);
      expect(style.cursor).toEqual('not-allowed');
      expect(style.opacity).not.toEqual('1')
    });
  });
```

As you can see each test consists of a `describe`, a `beforeEach` and the `it`. This is a lot to me and when the test fails, I get some useless timeout error.

Here is what I get when the tests work:

```
Enabled button (no disabled attribute)
  ✓ should be enabled
Enabled button (disabled="{ false }")
  ✓ should be enabled
Disabled button (disabled)
  ✗ should be disabled
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

It fails anyway, the test passed but the timeout caused a fail. I'm trying to test that the click event didn't happen. Also it's 6 lines, two for each test. I really would much rather have this:

```
✓ Enabled button (no disabled attribute)
✓ Enabled button (disabled="{ false }")
✓ Disabled button (disabled)
```

I need to have the negative test work, the testing for the lack of a click.

When the test does really fail, I get this, the same timeout crud along with the valid failure reason.

```
  ✗ should be enabled
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Expected false to equal true.
    at Object.<anonymous> (ui-button.spec.js:89:23)
```

Is there some way to test for the lack of an event? Is there some other, better way, I can write my spec file? I only listed 3 tests here but I have a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Easier one is to add negative test into describe where there is no `beforeEach` where click handler executes `done()` callback. You obviously can't click on disabled HTML element.

2.
Change your `beforeEach` for example like this (crucial is to execute `done()` callback at some point in `beforeEach`):

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
  // Create the tag
  el = document.createElement('rui-button')
  el.innerHTML = 'Test Button';
  el.setAttribute('disabled', '');
  document.body.appendChild(el)

  el.addEventListener('click', function () {
    clicked = true;
    done();
  });

  // Mount the tag
  tag = riot.mount('rui-button')[0]
  expect(tag).toBeDefined();
  expect(tag.isMounted).toBe(true);
  tag.update();

  if (el.getAttribute('data-disabled')) {
    done();
  } else {
    el.childNodes[0].click();      
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if the click happened Jasmine will break because the `done` function will have been called twice.